# NTFS drive isn't writable even after installing Fuse

Tags: mac, high-sierra, homebrew, filesystem, ntfs

I have installed fuse using steps which are linked below in an article. Each and every step was successful but after mounting my WD external drive, still it was not writable. Everywhere I found same steps. I am currently using macOS high Sierra 10.13.4 on my MacBook Pro.
After installing Paragon for WD drives only, it worked for my WD drive but FUSE still does not support or come into action as I plug my another Sony's 1 TB external hard drive.
Is there any problem with FUSE?

[Link to install FUSE & ntfs-3g](https://medium.com/@technikhil/setting-up-ntfs-3g-on-your-mac-os-sierra-11eff1749898)

Comment: Can you edit the question to provide the link to the article that you followed to install FUSE for macOS?

Comment: okay, I have done that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced similar problem with my WD external 1 TB drive. Despite installing [FUSE](https://osxfuse.github.io), my drive was mounted in read only mode.

Turns out, for writing to WD external drives formatted with NTFS you will need to install a proprietary NTFS driver for macOS called **Paragon NTFS Driver for Mac**.

You can follow the instructions on this support article on WD website, [How to Install the Paragon NTFS Driver for Mac](https://support.wdc.com/knowledgebase/answer.aspx?ID=20717#subject2).

Comment: is it paid version or specially only for WD? like Seagate provides free Paragon for their drives only.

Comment: After installing Paragon for WD drives only, it worked for my WD drive but FUSE still does not support or come into action as I plug my another Sony's 1 TB external hard drive. Is there any problem with FUSE?

Comment: I have FUSE reliably in the past. Apparently it has stopped working with the recent versions of macOS.